# c# Loop not incrementing as expected

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

Hi I had a loop that was stepping through an array with each index being multiplied by two. However I changed it so that the index is multiplied by 0, then 1, then 2 etc til it hits 10. (This is j in the code below) j is not incrementing as expected and just multiplies by nine. Can anyone help? Tks

```
using System;

namespace ArrayandStringPractice
{
  class MainClass
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int[] a = new int[10];

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
          {
            a[i] = i * j;
            //Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
          }
        }

      foreach (int i in a)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are doing a series of multiplications of `i` by 0 to 9 and store each result in `a[i]` of course `a[i]` can store only one value: the last one, i.e. `i*9`

Comment: Did you mean to use `+=` ?  It might help to learn to use the single-step feature of your debugger so you can see the different values and what is being stored at each step.

Comment: +=? Im not sure where you are referring to. Looking into the debugging now.

Comment: @Eric - Your `{`/`}` are wrong for your `for` loops. The first set of braces should be after the first `for`. You have both sets nested under the second one.

Answer (score 1):

With the line

```
a[i] = i * j;
```

`i` remains the same value for the entire cycle of the loop using `j`, this means you are continuously overwriting the value placed in `a[i]`.

With the new algorithmn you are using, you are effectively storing the square of `i` at each index of the array, so this will be enough:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    a[i] = i * i;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your for-loop for j

a[i] = i * j;

above line of code will always overwrite by last value of j which is 9
so, you will get 
i = 1..9, multiple fixed j=9.

```
using System;

namespace ArrayandStringPractice
{
  class MainClass
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int[] a = new int[10];

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
          {
            a[i] = i * j;
            //Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
          }
        }

      foreach (int i in a)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Im breaking it down getting my head around the 'storing' part before I move on!

Answer (score 0):

Use a two dimensional array to store all the values:

```
int[,] a = new int[10,10];
```

Then replace

```
a[i] = i * j;
```

with

```
a[i,j] = i * j;
```

and use this to read the values back:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        Console.WriteLine(a[i,j]);
```